# Polymer dom-repeat don't load attributes to child elements

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have the following code in a Polymer web component:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sections}}">
  <paper-item data-page="{{item.name}}" on-tap="changeTab" sectionid="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
</template>
```

where `sections` is defined as follows:

```
sections: {
  type: Array,
  value: [
    {
      name: 'Chaquetas',
      id: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Camisas',
      id: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Pantalones',
      id: '3'
    },
    {
      name: 'Faldas',
      id: '4'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chaquetas',
      id: '5'
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is that after rendering the HTML, the properties `data-page` and `sectionid` are not shown in the element inspector on `<paper-item>`, while `item.name` shows correctly, as shown below.

```
<paper-item class="style-scope blackbart-app x-scope paper-item-0" role="option" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
    Chaquetas
</paper-item>
(...)
```

Can someone explain to me what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code you have binds `item.name` to a **property** of `<paper-item>` named `dataPage`; and `item.id` to a **property** named `sectionid`. Properties would not appear in the inspector as an attribute on your element.

To bind an attribute, use Polymer's [attribute-binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#anatomy-of-a-data-binding) (i.e., `attr-name$=binding`):

```
<paper-item data-page$="[[item.name]]" sectionid$="[[item.id]]">
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [{
          name: 'Chaquetas',
          id: '1'
        }, {
          name: 'Camisas',
          id: '2'
        }, {
          name: 'Pantalones',
          id: '3'
        }, {
          name: 'Faldas',
          id: '4'
        }, {
          name: 'Chaquetas',
          id: '5'
        }]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-menu>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
          <paper-item data-page$="[[item.name]]" sectionid$="[[item.id]]">[[item.name]]</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jMgEjV?editors=1010)